# How to make video background responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My background video is displaying correctly on full sized laptops/desktop display but when I start to minimize it gets clunky and the video zooms in on a building and its height too long on the mobile display.

What media queries can I use to make this video background more responsive?

It doesn't have to be perfect on mobile but somewhat decent.

```css
.fullscreen-bg {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1px;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    height: 300%;
    top: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    width: 300%;
    left: -100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('../img/videoframe.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
  }
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/index-11.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="video/BnW.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="video/BnW.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="container container-wide slider-container">
      <div class="jumbotron text-center bg-btn">
        <h1 data-wow-duration="2s" class="wow fadeIn">Beautiful.<br>Views.<small data-wow-duration="2s" class="wow fadeIn">City of Chicago</small></h1>
        <p data-wow-duration="2s" class="big wow fadeIn"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Responsive does not necessarily mean or require media queries. Your video can be responsive simply by giving the `video` element a relative size for `width` or `height` (not both) and then we would typically set a value for `min-` and `max-` `height/width` to keep the sizing to limits. With media queries (which certainly are great), you will encounter "break points", where a new query kicks in and all of a sudden, your content will "snap" to the styling of the new query. Using relative sizes doesn't cause this.

Comment: You also are setting the `height` in one media query and the `width` in another - - be consistent. Use the same property in all media queries or make sure to reset any earlier set properties in a new media query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
position: relative;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It's best to include some explanation rather than just a proposed solution. Why does this work?

Comment: And some guidance. Where would you like the OP to put that code?